# Tengo dos valores que son iguales y dice que son diferentes

Tags: java, poo, eclipse

estoy haciendo un login en Java con la clase y al momento de comparar los dos valores (correo y contraseña) introducidos con los fijos me dice que son diferentes, aquí el código:

```
persona persona1 = new persona("paula");
persona1.setMail("paula@hot.com");
persona1.setPassword("contra123");
if(isValid(mailTxt.getText())==true&&passwordTxt.getText().length()>=8) {
System.out.println("Correcto my dude");     if(persona1.getMail()==mailTxt.getText()&&persona1.getPassword()==passwordTxt.getText()) {
                    System.out.println("CORRECTO :)");
                }
                else {
                    if(mailTxt.getText()!=persona1.getMail())
                        System.out.println("correo incorrecto");
                        System.out.println(mailTxt.getText());
                    if(passwordTxt.getText()!=persona1.getPassword()) 
                        System.out.println("contraseña incorrecto");
                        System.out.println(passwordTxt.getText());
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("INCORRECTO :(");
            }
        }
```

Este es el resultado que me da cuando pongo EXACTAMENTE EL MISMO correo y contraseña :(

[image: Este es el resultado que me da cuando pongo EXACTAMENTE EL MISMO correo y contraseña :(]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te ocurre es que estás comparando dos objetos de tipo `String` utilizando el operador `==`. Este operador usado sobre objetos SIEMPRE compara referencias y como ambas referencias son diferentes, aunque el contenido de los Strings sea el mismo, pues se evalúa como `false`.

Para solucionarlo utiliza en vez de `==` el método `equals()`.

```
persona1.getMail().equals(mailTxt.getText())// es tru si ambas cadenas contienen el mismo valor
```

Hay casos en los que si funciona el operador `==` aplicado sobre objetos de tipos `String`, pero debes estudiar un poco el tema para que veas como funciona. Mira esta artículo: [Java String Pool , un concepto importante](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/java-string-pool-un-concepto-importante/)

Como recomendación general, evita utilizar el operador `==` sobre Strings, te evitará este tipo de problemas aparentemente sin sentido.

Comment: Correcto. Buen aporte. Un saludo.

Comment: oooh es verdad! Un año sin programar en Java hace daño jaja. Muchísimas graciaaaas 

Comment: Un placer ayudarte. Saludos!